# Google Earth Engine doesn't preserve functions when exporting with GEE Python API and geemap

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I  want to export images from a collections locally to integrate them in other application. I want to skip the part where I must download them from my Google drive with some command line. For that I use [geemap](https://geemap.org/), which is a great package for extra work with GEE.

I have applied all the functions on my collection and also I visualize the result. The results are correct, with the expected view on visualization part. When I export one image from the list of images, the image is incorrect, like somehow the filtering wasn't applied. And from my logic, the flaw must be with the export part. I also tried with a lot of a smaller geometry, I thought that the dimension of the resulted image was the problem. Same result.

Any ideas on this issue?

Maybe I am doing something wrong when I apply the functions.

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())

import os
import ee
import geemap
Map=geemap.Map()

###geometry import
pol3 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([20.368833429599636,43.714615900838105, 
28.718442804599633,48.391893737144606])

#########################function area
## a function to extract values from specific bits 
def bitwiseExtract(input, fromBit, toBit):
    maskSize=ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
    mask=ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
    return input.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)

# A function to mask out low quality zones 
def qa_mask(image):
    # Select the QA band.
    QA = image.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover_Basic_QA')
    qaMask=bitwiseExtract(QA, 0, 15).lte(2)
    return image.updateMask(qaMask)


 ###mask for filtering out images with smaller number of value counts per decade
 def mask_count(image):
     maskCount=image.select('NDSI_count').gte(2)
     image1=image.select('NDSI_max').updateMask(maskCount)
     return image1.select('NDSI_max')

###function to filter out areas with an altitude lower than 2000
def filtru_elev(image):
    elevatie=ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4').select('elevation').gte(2000);
    image1=image.updateMask(elevatie);
    return image1;


###GLS water dataset to filter out all regions that are covered with lakes, pond, big 
rivers etc.
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('GLCF/GLS_WATER').select('water').min()
# Remap values.
water = ee.Image(1)\
      .where(dataset.lte(1), 0)\
      .where(dataset.eq(2), 1)\
      .where(dataset.gte(3),0);

###Mask for NDSI values greater than 30 
def masker(image):
    test=water.select('constant').eq(0)
    test2=image.updateMask(test)
    mask1 = test2.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover').gt(30)
    return image.updateMask(mask1)

###function for band name size for additional filtering out images with 0 bands
def nb_bands(image):
    return image.set('numar',image.bandNames().size())


##NDSI clip and renaming function
def func_dko(image):
    return image.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover').rename('NDSI').clip(pol3).copyProperties(image,['system:time_start','system:time_end'])
########################################################################
#####################################imagee colections

col1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1').map(qa_mask)
NDSI = col1.map(masker).map(func_dko)
elev=ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4').select('elevation');

############################################################
#define starting and ending dates
startyear = 2001
endyear = 2002
mapYears = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear)
startmonth = 6
endmonth =1
mapMonths = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)
start = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear, startmonth, 1)
end = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear, endmonth+1, 1); # end date is always exclusive

# define list of dates to filter on
startdays = ee.List([1, 11, 21])
enddays = ee.List([11, 21, 1])
# Create a sequence of numbers, one for each time interval.
sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, 2)

##functie creare decade
def collect(collection, start, end, mapYears, mapMonths):
    def func_years(year):
        def func_months(month):
            def func_sequence(dayRange):
                startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, startdays.get(dayRange))
                                # the end date needs some if statements to be well formatted
                endDate = ee.Date(ee.Algorithms.If( ee.Number(dayRange).eq(2), \
                                                    ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(month).eq(12), \
                                                                     ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1), 1, enddays.get(dayRange)),\
                                                                     ee.Date.fromYMD(year, ee.Number(month).add(1), enddays.get(dayRange))),\
                                                     ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, enddays.get(dayRange))))
                                                     
                return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).reduce(ee.Reducer.max().combine(reducer2=ee.Reducer.count(), sharedInputs=True)).set('system:time_start', startDate.millis()).set('system:time_end', endDate.millis()).set('numbImages',collection.size()).set('dateYMD', startDate.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
            images2 = sequence.map(func_sequence)
            return images2
        images1 = mapMonths.map(func_months)
        return images1
    images=mapYears.map(func_years).flatten()
    collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images)
    return collection.filterDate(start, end)#.set('system:time_start', start.millis()).set('system:time_end', end.millis())



###start applying functions for the image collection
###ten days maximum value composite
NDSI_decadal = collect(NDSI, start, end, mapYears, mapMonths);

#######NDSI filtering out images with 0 bands and elevation
####temporal filtering of wrongly identified snow for summer months under the elevation of 2000 meters
final_init=NDSI_decadal.map(nb_bands)
final_init_part=final_init.filter(ee.Filter.gte("numar",2))
with_elev_summer=final_init_part.map(filtru_elev).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 10, 'month'));

####some joins to create a final imageCollections 
sceneFilter = ee.Filter.equals(
leftField = 'dateYMD',
rightField = 'dateYMD')

###create an inverted join to keep just the images with a number of bands greater than 2 
but without the elevation and temporal filtering
inverted_join = ee.Join.inverted()
coll_inverted = inverted_join.apply(final_init_part, with_elev_summer, sceneFilter);
######join the 2 collections, the filtered out and unfiltered 
without_elev_summer=ee.ImageCollection(coll_inverted).map(mask_count)
final_NDSI=without_elev_summer.merge(with_elev_summer).sort('system:time_start', True)

#########################
###list for visualization

lista=final_NDSI.select('NDSI_max').toList(200)
imagine=ee.Image(lista.get(1))
data_imagine = imagine.date().format('dd-MM-yyyy').getInfo()
print(data_imagine)
ndsiParams = {'min': -1, 'max':100, 'palette': ['8B0000','FF0000', 'FF4500', 'FFFF00', 
'00FF00','008000', '006400']}
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(lista.get(1)), ndsiParams, 'NDSI image')
Map

#####export part 
out_dir = os.path.expanduser("Downloads2")
if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
   os.makedirs(out_dir)


imag=ee.Image(lista.get(0))
date = ee.Date(imag.get('system:time_start')).format('dd-MM-yyyy').getInfo()
name1= 'SnowDecad'+'_'+date+'.tif'
filename1 = os.path.join(out_dir, name1)
print(name1)
geemap.ee_export_image(imag, filename=filename1, scale=500,region=pol3, crs='EPSG:3035')
```